# Alternatives to WebContext.forwardToString()

Tags: java, jsp, servlets, dwr

The problem sounds like this :
In my application i must get off java DWR technologies.So it will be basically more jquery.:)
Now i'm trying to find a way to replace

```
WebContext.forwardToString()
```

Does somebody knows a way to replace it using `HttpServletRequest` / `Response` or some `HttpUtil` class?

Or externalize the jsp file which i will populated in controller?

Comment: Ending up using this solution  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/701681/how-can-i-read-an-httpservletreponses-output-stream

Comment: I end up using this solution : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/701681/how-can-i-read-an-httpservletreponses-output-stream