# Intercept JSON message - Eclipse RAP

Tags: java, json, eclipse-rcp, eclipse-rap

Is there a way to intercept and record every JSON message exchanged between a Eclipse RAP-Client and a RAP-Server?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The best way to do this is a [servlet filter](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/5/api/javax/servlet/Filter.html). See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/702392/247159) for an example how to read the response in a filter.

As an alternative, you could register a [PhaseListener](http://download.eclipse.org/rt/rap/doc/2.2/guide/reference/api/org/eclipse/rap/rwt/lifecycle/PhaseListener.html) and try to hook into RWT's internal APIs such as ClientMessage and ProtocolMessageWriter. However, these internals are subject to change and even the PhaseListener interface will be deprecated and likely removed in RAP 3. Therefore, I wouldn't recommend this approach.

Comment: Thank you for the answer.
How can i set this servlet filter to intercept any communication between client and server?

Comment: If you're using RWT standalone, you can configure the servlet filter in your web.xml. If OSGi, please see [this thread](http://www.eclipse.org/forums/index.php/t/627876/).